# C — using chdir() function

Tags: c, linux, cmd, console, chdir

I'm trying to use `chdir()` function but can't work it out.

I'm reading from user and find out if he is using "cd".
I always get an error.
What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
    int * status=0;
    char * buf = 0;
    char arguments[2048];
    buf = getcwd(buf,PATH_MAX);
    printf("%s >",buf);

    fgets(arguments,2048,stdin);

    if( strncmp(arguments,"quit",4)==0 ){
      printf("Exit...\n");
      break;
    }
    else if(strncmp(arguments,"cd",2)==0 ){
        int ret;
        printf("\nGOT = %s\n",(arguments+2));
        ret = chdir ((arguments+2));
        if(ret!=0){
          perror("Error:");
        }
    }
```

Comment: ... and that error would be what, exactly?

Comment: GOT = /home

Error:: No such file or directory

Comment: That'll be a newline at the end of the input, see my answer.

Comment: BTW, you could use `strace` and `gdb` to debug your issue. That would be faster than asking here....

Comment: Study the source code of some small free software shell like `sash`

Comment: ahi plili shelha ahi. caspl lab 5? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the line being entered is something like:

```
cd xyzzy
```

then the directory starts at offset 3, not 2. In addition, `fgets` usually gives you a line with a newline character at the end so you'll want to remove that as well, such as:

```
if (strlen (line) > 0)
    if (line[strlen (line) - 1] == '\n')
        line[strlen (line) - 1] = '\0';
```

You should probably be tokenising the input a little more intelligently, a shell like `bash` (for example) has rather complex rules.

Comment: Thanks it worked

just added 

arguments[strlen(arguments)-1] = '\0';

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a space character after `"cd"`, so you should add 3 not 2.

```
    printf("\nGOT = %s\n",(arguments+3));
    ret = chdir ((arguments+3));
```

Comment: yeah I tried that I'm getting:
"
GOT = /home

Error:: No such file or directory